# Django computation in using aggregate method

Tags: python, django

I have this computation in my views that using filter and aggregate method

**first** is i distinct the **StudentSubjectGrade**

**second** I filter the related field in **StudentSubjectGrade** .

**Third** i use aggregate to compute the average and for every grading categories i have to multiply it by its PercentageWeight.

this is the computation

***average = average * Grading_Categories__PercentageWeight / 100***

```
students = StudentSubjectGrade.objects.filter(
    grading_Period=period).filter(
    Subjects=subject).order_by(
    'Students_Enrollment_Records', 'Grading_Categories','id'
).values('id','Grading_Categories','Average', 'Grading_Categories__PercentageWeight')

overall = StudentSubjectGrade.objects.filter(
    grading_Period=period).filter(
    Subjects=subject).aggregate(average_grade=Avg('Average') * students[
        'Grading_Categories__PercentageWeight'] / 100)
```

this is their models

```
class StudentSubjectGrade(models.Model):
    GradeLevel = models.ForeignKey(EducationLevel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    Subjects = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    Students_Enrollment_Records = models.ForeignKey(StudentsEnrolledSubject,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    Grading_Categories = models.ForeignKey(gradingCategories,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)
    grading_Period = models.ForeignKey(gradingPeriod,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)
    Gradedates = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    Average = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)

class gradingCategories(models.Model):
    CategoryName = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    PercentageWeight = models.FloatField()
```

this is the error i get

[image]

**UPDATE** when i tried this

```
overall = StudentSubjectGrade.objects.filter( grading_Period=period).filter( Subjects=subject).aggregate(average_grade=Avg('Average') * F( 'Grading_Categories__PercentageWeight') / 100 )
```

I received this error

[image]

Comment: The problem is here `students['Grading_Categories__PercentageWeight']`, students is a queryset, and you can't use a string there.

Comment: @Huskell then what should I do?

Comment: I think you need to aggregate `Grading_Categories__PercentageWeight` before using in `F`

Comment: ive tried this also  ''' * students('Grading_Categories__PercentageWeight') / 100 ''' and I receive this error """""TypeError: 'QuerySet' object is not callable"""

Comment: @Huskell can you provide example using my code?